# Delphi 7 - How to delete an item from listview using its caption

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i'm trying to delete a listview item based into caption, but I can not find a solution for this, the only way I can delete an item is using the index:

```
listview1.Items.Delete (0);
```

Can anyone help me to delete an item through the caption?

Comment: @Wellisson Please start including the delphi tag, as well as delphi-7 in your questions. This will make sure that as many people as possible see them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like this, which attempts to locate a `ListItem` with the caption `Item 2`, and deletes it if it find it:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LI: TListItem;
begin
  LI := ListView1.FindCaption(0, 'Item 2', False, True, False);
  if Assigned(LI) then
  begin
    ListView1.Selected := LI;
    ListView1.DeleteSelected;
  end;
end;
```

An alternative which does not require you to select the item first would be to delete the found item by its `Index`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LI: TListItem;
begin
  LI := ListView1.FindCaption(0, 'Item 2', False, True, False);
  if Assigned(LI) then
    ListView1.Items.Delete(LI.Index);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); var LI: TListItem; begin LI := ListView1.Selected; if Assigned(LI) then begin ListView1.Selected := LI; ListView1.DeleteSelected; end; end;

Comment: The OP asked how to delete an item using its caption to find it, not how to delete the selected item.