# Delphi 7 - How to remove a Listview item caption when a client socket disconnect

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm triyng to delete a item caption from a listview when a client socket disconnect from a server socket. In my code when a client connect to a server the listview add a icon and a caption (client.hostname), but how to delete the item when client disconnect?  `Listview1.items.delete.caption(socket.host)`. Any help?

I'll try to explain despite my bad english: All I need is to delete an item from listview so the client socket disconnect. Mr. Ken White gave me a solution to a question almost identical however I'm not managing to fit it in a situation where several clients are connected to the server ie, how can I delete the listview caption belonging to the host who just disconnect?

My serversocket1 code: (i renamed serversocket1 to socket1)

```
procedure TForm1.socket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin

ListView1.AddItem(Socket.RemoteHost, socket);
end;
```

Code that i using to try delete the item when client disconnect:

```
procedure TForm1.socket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
L : TListItem;
begin
L:=listview1.FindCaption(0,inttostr(socket.Handle),false,true,false);
if L<>nil then 
L.Delete;
end;
```

But the listview item don't delete.

Comment: Is there a reason that the code I posted to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427876/delphi-7-how-to-delete-an-item-from-listview-using-its-caption/19428124#19428124) doesn't work for this as well? You haven't explained what the problem is you're trying to solve here. Can you please [edit] to do so?

Comment: Welisson, you still haven't given us any information about how what's in the `ListView` relates to the host. What information are you storing in the `ListView.Caption` that relates to what property in the `Socket`? (`TCustomWinSocket` doesn't have a `Host` property - it has either a `LocalHost` or a `RemoteHost`, and even if one of those are what you're referencing we don't know how it relates to your `ListItem.Caption` at all.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the index of the added item first, ie Listview1.items.IndexOf(socket.host) and then delete the item at that specific index.

Comment: `ListView.Items.IndexOf` requires you already have a `TListItem` to pass as a parameters. See the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItems.IndexOf), which declares it as `TListItems.IndexOf(Value: TListItem): Integer`. Your code won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code:

```
procedure TForm1.socket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
L : TListItem;
begin
L:=listview1.FindCaption(0,inttostr(socket.Handle),false,true,false);
if L<>nil then 
L.Delete;
end;
```

to this:

```
procedure TForm1.socket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
L : TListItem;
begin
L:=listview1.FindCaption(0,socket.remotehost,false,true,false); // <--changed this line socket.remotehost

if L<>nil then 
begin
L.Delete;
end;
end;
```

And it's works,Just not sure if I made the right way. Thanks for all.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You're storing the `Socket.RemoteHost` as the caption of your `ListItem` in `ListView1.AddItem`, so you should also be using `Socket.RemoteHost` in the call to `ListView1.FindCaption`. Depending on what your code is doing with the `Socket` afterward, you may need to free the `Socket` before deleting the `ListItem` returned by `FindCaption`, but I can't tell that from your code snippet.